# TCL Clock command

Tags: tcl

The below shown clock manipulation works well in Linux machine which has TCL 8.5. But when I use the same on the SunOS which has the TCL8.4 , I am getting the error "bad switch "-format": must be -base or -gmt".

For some reason, I am not able to upgrade my TCL 8.4 to 8.5 in SunOS.

How can I make it work in TCL 8.4 as well?

The commands are given below and what I am trying to achieve through these commands is to advance the system date by one more day.

$today contains the value "2012 06 15 14 39 20"

```
set today [clock scan $today -format "%Y %m %d %H %M %S"]      
set tomorrow [clock add $today 86600 seconds]
set victim [clock format $tomorrow -format "%a"]
set tomorrow [clock format $tomorrow -format "%m%d%H%M"]
send "sudo date $tomorrow\r"
```

Answer (score 5):

[Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11046360/301832) is the core of what the issue is: 8.5 added a lot of features to `clock` and your code is dependent on them. However, he doesn't quite identify the best method for getting the target time.

```
# Multiple assignment from list
foreach {YY MM DD HH mm ss} $today break
# Get the date tomorrow in one funky step
set tomorrow [clock scan "$YY$MM$DD $HH$mm$ss + 86600 seconds"]

# Rest is the same as before
set victim [clock format $tomorrow -format "%a"]
set tomorrow [clock format $tomorrow -format "%m%d%H%M"]
send "sudo date $tomorrow\r"
```

(You are aware that a day is never 86600 seconds long? That's 200 seconds longer than the average length…)

Comment: @Jackson Yes, but use `lassign` from 8.5 onwards, please.

Comment: Thx Donal. I will try this. BTW, 200 seconds longer is intentional to add some additional seconds to the next day.

Comment: @Prakash OK, it was just weirdly longer than a day. :-) More to the point, you should also be aware that daylight savings rules means that not all days are 24 hours long everywhere. Time (and date) handling is _absurdly_ complicated.

Comment: Yes Donal, It is complicated enough.. But I am lucky at the moment as I don't have to worry much about daylight savings etc.. But can't escape from future requirements though... Thanks Donal

Comment: Donal, just a quick question.
Is it possible to add some seconds to the clock using tcl 8.4?
I know that it is possible in 8.5, but not sure if possible in 8.4.
Also, I got the error when I tried use 'add' with 'clock' command in 8.4
At the moment I just added n seconds to the clock seconds output, just like a normal arithmetic operation. Is this possible in 8.4 using a valid clock command??

Comment: My current code is,
#today contains, for example --> "15-June-2012 16:38:47"
set today [clock scan $today]
#now today contains, --> 1339742327
#set tomorrow [clock add $today 86600 seconds]  --> "GOT ERROR HERE"
set tomorrow [expr $today + 86600]    --> mathematically adding seconds
set victim [clock format $tomorrow -format "%a"]
set tomorrow [clock format $tomorrow -format "%m%d%H%M"]
send "sudo date $tomorrow\r"

Answer (score 2):

As you have found out the clock command changed between Tcl 8.4 and 8.5.  In 8.4 the clock scan command only recognized a number of standard formats. So you need to convert your $today value into one of these formats, see [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/clock.htm#M45) for details.

One possible way is

```
regexp {(\d\d\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d)} $today all YY MM DD HH mm ss
set reformatToday "$YY$MM$DD $HH$mm$ss"
set today [clock scan $reformatToday]
```

Tcl 8.5 will also work with this free form scan code; however this feature is deprecated in Tcl versions later than 8.4.

Comment: Thanks jack, I am gonna try this.